# stdout to disk file, with frequency limitation

Tags: go

```golang
if file, err := os.Create(os.TempDir() + "/stdout.txt"); nil == err {
  // todo buffer write
  os.Stdout = file
  os.Stderr = file  
} else {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This will write the output of the process to the disk, but without frequency control, it may cause a heavy burden on the disk. How to add a buffer to the write operation?

The trouble is that `os.Stdout` is not an interface, but `*os.File`

```golang
os.Stdout = bufio.NewWriter(file) // error
```

Comment: Go has no defacto solution for this situation right now. Most modules which want to write streaming data or print logs will provide **some** API for you to control it. If you depend on modules which directly write to `os.Stdout`/`os.Stderr` (whatever their values may be) when they shouldn't, you probably should file an issue on it. What you can do is make your own writer and try to make everything use it instead of going to `os.Stdout`/`os.Stderr` directly. Worst case you can set both to write to `/dev/null` to shut up unwanted noise, though even that might fail when CGO is used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify in detail what limitations you actually want on the writer, but you can add a buffer that batches writes until they are a certain size using `bufio.Writer` in the standard library. A small implementation note is that you have to be careful to flush the buffer before you close the underlying writer to avoid losing output data.

Comment: Yes, but I want to forward the output on a basic level, so that even if the package is written by someone else, it can handle it.